# How to put images to media folder on install (J1.7)?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

I have mu install.xml file with:

```
    <media destination="com_mycomp/images" folder="media">
        <filename>images/file1.png</filename>
        <filename>images/file2.gif</filename>
    </media>
```

and during the installation folders are created but do not copy the files? Why?

My component folder structure:

```
com_mycomp
|
install.xml
|
+--- site
|    |
|    + (...)
|
+--- admin
|    |
|    + (...)
|
+--- media
     |
     + images
       |
       + file1.png
       |
       + file2.gif
```

How to put files to media folder on installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<media destination="com_mycomp" folder="media"> 
     <folder>images</folder>
</media>
```

use this sample code and it will upload all file in images folder